# Recycler view performance

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

When notifying a recycler view using notifyItemRangeChanged() even with a no-op bindViewHolder(), it is requesting a layout of the entire view hierarchy. Anyone knows why and if there is a way to avoid it?

Comment: If you have set the Recyclerview to wrap_content, it would make sense for the parent to need to redraw. Otherwise, I'm not sure how you're monitoring that action

Comment: @cricket_007 do you mean how do I monitor that the parent is being laid out? I just added a log to the parent's onLayout(). And no, I am not using wrap_content however I am setting the width and height to match parent. Does that have any link?